# Make link clickable

Tags: php, url

My code replacing "default" link to clickable link if you know what i mean ;/
When in text is only 1 url all woks fine but when in string is more than 1 url all links begin to be the same.
On example

"Here is my first video LINK1 and here is my second video LINK2"

After do function this text look like this:

"Here is my first video LINK1 and here is my second video LINK1"

LINK2 begin to be LINK1

My function

```
function DoLinks($link){
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

    $text = $link;
    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
        // DO IT!
        $linh = $url[0];
        return preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a class='linka' href='$linh'>$linh</a> ", $text);
    } else {
        return $text;
    }
}
```

My question is how to do that LINK2 begin to be LINK2 not LINK1

Comment: What is the question? Shouldn't need the `preg_match`.

Comment: Maybe, https://eval.in/558898?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something like:

```
function DoLinks($text) {   
    return preg_replace ('/((?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:\/\S*)?)/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
}
```